# How to compare each line of matrix with elements of vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I would like to compare each line of given matrix with all elements of given vector:

```
matrix <- matrix(c(c("var1","var2"),c("var4","var5"),c("var6","var7")),nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
vector <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6")
```

The desired outcome would be just: TRUE because the elements of first line of matrix are contained within given vector.

If the matrix was defined as:

```
matrix <- matrix(c(c("var6","var7"),c("var1","var8"),c("var2","var9")),nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
```

The the desired outcome would be in this case FALSE because the elements of all rows of matrix are not contained within given vector. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need `apply` here

```
apply(matrix, 1, function(x) all(x %in% vector))
```

This looks across all the rows of the matrix to see if all values in a given row are in the vector.

Comment: Actually, this looks at columns! `MARGIN` is set to `2`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for the heads up. I've fixed the answer.